# Raspberry Pi 4 doesn't boot - autoboot.txt not found

Tags: pi-4, boot-issues

I have Raspberry Pi 4 (4GB), it worked fine for months (nextcloud server on it), but few days ago I noticed that site doesn't work, connected monitor and found out that it doesn't boot successfully anymore, there are several "not founds" on screen:
**autoboot.txt**, **recover4.elf**, **recovery.elf**, **start4.elf**, **start.elf**
there is another error "**firmware not found**" and "**SD boot failed**", "**BOOT_STOPPED: 0x00000001 0x0**".
I thought files were lost and searched them on my another pi (not Pi4) and couldn't find most of them there too).
I can't find any meaningful solution for this issue, is there any way to restore system to it's working stats somehow?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Not all of these files are needed for all situations. Which OS + version? Can you read the SD card in another computer?

Comment: yes sd card is readable in another computer, os is raspbian

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're getting (not "several not founds on screen"), and list the files you have on the boot partition. Did you check your SD card for damage by the way?

Comment: please see screenshot  https://ibb.co/LdKVtr9

Comment: site doesn't allow to attach screenshots, I will enter all the errors manually later.

Comment: @BekaShvelidze Yeah I feel your pain. Damn spammers made stack exchange rather restrictive for new users...

Comment: site says maybe entering code is better when I try to insert image 

Comment: Seems the boot partition is broken. You should restore the SD Card from your backup.

Comment: I had to clean sd card and write system from scratch.